# clone from github with pycharm files

Tags: python, git, github, pycharm

So I created a python project in Pycharm, then I set up a git there (using GitHub desktop), with python .gitignore file template, I created a repository there. I pushed it to GitHub, created branches and commits. Now let's say I want to clone my project to another computer - so if I'm doing clone from GitHub desktop, it gets my files but it's not a Paycharm project anymore.
and if I create first the pycharm project there, it won't let me clone there because it's not a clear folder.

so my question is - how can I set up my project there, so it will be a pycharm project with all my files and changes from GitHub?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The project infromation of a pycharm project is saved in the `.idea` folder. If you want to share the pycharm project via git, you have to make sure to commit some files of the `.idea` folder.

You can find all files you need to commit here: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839-How-to-manage-projects-under-Version-Control-Systems

> Here is what you need to share:
> All the files under the .idea directory in the project root except the workspace.xml, usage.statistics.xml, and tasks.xml files and the shelf directory which store user-specific settings

Comment: Yes I did it, I have all the files from .idea folder. But I still can't figure out how to create the project in another computer, because if I'm cloning my project, I can't open it on pycharm and run it because it's not a project any more. What is the steps that I need to do so I can open and run my project in another computer?

Comment: Ok so I will write my steps:
first, Im cloning my project to an empty folder. then, I open Pycharm, select "open", select my folder and open it. Now, I open my main file but I can't run it, it says "Invalid Python interpreter selected for the project". I remember when I create a project in Pycharm it also creates venv folder, which is missing here. maybe that is the problem? what should I do?

Comment: You need to be careful with copying .idea folder over as python interpreter is with absolute path. It contains stuff like this: `<option name="SDK_HOME" value="/Applications/anaconda3/bin/python" />`. Note the absolute path. If you don't have the same installation, it will complain of this.

Comment: The `venv` that was set up usually have symlinks to the `python` version on your first machine, so you will have issues I think.

Comment: Guys thank you so much!
just realized how stupid I am. I copied all files correctly, with gitignore file. 
all I had to do is create an interpreter in my new folder using pycharm - and not it's working perfectly! thanks for your help!